# Disable Widget movement in flutter on keyboard events

Tags: flutter, dart, android-softkeyboard

I have this simple search_home.dart page that shows a TextField and Text widgets. The code and demo are shown below.

My issue is that on keyboard events, the Text widget moves up and down, which doesn't look nice. I've tried other solutions using `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` but no success. What can be changed here to disable the movements?

[image: demo]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 350.0 * animation.value,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.elliptical(2000, 350),
                  bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(1000, 100),
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100 * animation.value),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 18.0,
                        vertical: 18.0,
                      ),
                      filled: true,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Search for Campuses, Courses and VR Videos!',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hey, for me your code is working fine. Maybe it's a problem due to hot reload. Try to restart your app and test it.

Comment: @divyanshubhargava Hmm, odd, I tried to hot restart, and that didn't work. So, I re-built the app in debug mode. No luck. Then I built an apk and installed in on a device, still no luck